# SMTP Port Filitering/Alternative Port

Tags: networking, dns, smtp, kerio

I am setting up Kerio Connect on a businss server, and have configured DNS records to point to new mail server. However i attempted a telnet from outside the network and recieved a 421 error. From what i have read, 9/10 it is an ISP port filtering issue?

As we lease an office in a large building (and i know little of how the networking works within such a building). Is there another port i can set up instead? or a way around this issue? I plan to double check with the ISP tomorrow (need to double check who the actual ISP first!)

Any sugeestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Can you telnet to it from inside? are you running a firewall? IF you have business internet they shouldn't be blocking any smtp ports.

Comment: Telnet from inside gave me this:

'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: you have to telnet to the port.  For instance if you are telnet'ing to an SMTP server you would do this:  telnet IP port OR telnet 192.168.0.1 25

Comment: Thats what i was doing when i got the telnet error above. ('telnet 192.168.1.6 25)

Comment: Telnet client wasnt enabled... now it tells me connection failed, is this because telnet may not be installed on server?

Comment: no, telnet can connect to any port not using encryption.  you need to make sure the port is opening and listening.  If you own the server and it's windows you need to open a cmd prompt and type netstat -ano and make sure whatever port it is your trying to attach to is listening

Comment: is port 25 the port you are trying to connect to?  Is Kerio Connect listening on port 25?